# Why does 'import mysql.connector' not work but 'from mysql import connector' does?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I'm starting to learn some SQL Python and upon starting I stumbled over this phenomenon. I can

```
from mysql import connector
```

but not

```
import mysql.connector
```

What is the reason for this?

[image: sql]

I can also leave away the import statement in the first line for the second line to still work.

Answer (score 1):

That would be because `import mysql.connector` implies that `connector` is a module, whereas `from mysql import connector` implies that it's an object/class/variable inside the module.

Comment: Aha, okay. Maybe it's possible this changed within the library? Because I simply followed https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp which is just literally the first baby step in testing the mysql-connector-python library.

Comment: Yeah, that's possible. Frankly, I think w3schools.com's content is kind of crap and can be very outdated and I hate it that they are always at the top of search results.

Comment: Thank you for this extra information, @ktdrv !